# Django internationalization with nested markup

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I'm using Django. I would like to make the following markup translatable:

```
You have <span class="blah">a flower</span> in your inbox.
```

I would have the following phrases in the translation file:

1. "You have {name} in your inbox."
2. "a flower"

Of course, I don't want to put markup in my translation file, but it should appear in the webpage as above.

In French for example, that would be:

```
Vous avez <span class="blah">une fleur</span> dans votre boite aux lettres.
```

I can't find how to achieve that cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [Internationalization: in template code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code)

You cab do this:

```
{% trans "You have " %} <span class="blah">{%trans "a flower" %} </span> {%trans " in your inbox." %}
```

You can also use `{% blocktrans %} ... {%endtblockrans%}` to mark a block to translate.

Comment: Then you end up with "You have " and " in your inbox." as phrases instead of "You have {name} in your inbox." like I mentioned in my question, and which is discouraged in about every book about localization.